# Django- Json data in template

Tags: json, django, django-templates

I am accessing an API and get JSON data. I can see that JSON is generated. However I am not able to show it in template.

Below is the sample Json data.

```
{  
   "response_code":1,
   "response":{  
      "a":"01/07/2017",
      "b":"12",
      "c":"23",
      "d":"34",
      "e":"45",
      "f":"56",

   },
   "error_code":null,
   "error_message":null
}
```

I passed this data in view to template as `dataset`.
View as asked in comment.

```
    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)  
json_string = json.dumps(response)
return render(request,'searchhome.html',{'dataset':json_string})
```

What I tried in template.

```
{% for key, value in dataset.items %}
{{key}}: {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Another try

```
{% for d in dataset %}
{% for key, value in d.response.items %}
{{key}} {{value}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Template is not showing any error or any response. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: please include view to show how you've passed the data

Comment: @HenryM Added view code

Comment: I am getting valid json data. Tested it on Json formatters online.

Comment: it might be as simple as `{% for key, value in dataset %}`

Comment: @HenryM That gives error Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 128.

Answer (score 3):

To iterate, you need it to be a python `dict` object and not the JSON string.

You can do it using the `json` package.

Example:

```
import json
string_containing_json = ".."
data = json.loads(string_containing_json)
```

Json is just a string arranged in special format. You need to convert it to python objects before using it.

EDIT: I have no idea why the downvote. Judging from the question, this is definitely the issue here. The OP is not converting the json string into dictionary. You can't iterate over a string, like you do a dictionary.

Comment: I dont know why you were downvoted either. Maybe the guy with the totally wrong answer wanted his to come first.

Answer (score 2):

You should not dump the data back to JSON in the view. Once you've done that, it's now a string, so it doesn't have an `items` method.

You should pass the result of `response.json()` directly to the template.

Answer (score 1):

I think, within the view, you need to convert the `response` like this:

```
import json

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)        
json_string = json.dumps(response)
return render(request,'searchhome.html',{'dataset':json_string})
```

And then, I think, you can access the data as

```
{{ dataset.response_code }}
{{ dataset.response.0 }}
```

etc

Comment: I used your code in view and now json comes in template when i type `{{dataset}}` but cannot iterate it. This does not work`{{ dataset.response_code }}
{{ dataset.response.0 }}`

Comment: Dumps is going to turn the json into an escaped javascript string. You want to pass a dict to the view not json.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could solve it.
My changed view:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    response = json.loads(response.content) 
    json_string = response["response"]
    return render(request,'searchhome.html',{'dataset':json_string})
```

My Template

```
{% for k,v in dataset.items %}
<tr>
<td>
{{k}}:{{v}}</td>
<tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Solution came with trying all answers posted and just adding `.content` to `json.loads(response)`